# If $F$ and $K$ are closed sets and $d(F,K)=0$ does it follow that $F\cap K\neq \emptyset$?

Tags: metric-spaces

If $F$ and $K$ are closed sets and $d(F,K)=0$ does it follow that $F\cap K\neq \emptyset$?  I can't find an example that it doesn't follow but I can't prove it either.
Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ (there are other examples)

Another: $F=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=0\}$, $K=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x\ne0, y=1/x\}$

---

Following the discussion in comments, if $K$ is compact then the conclusion is true. Indeed, if $d(F,K)=0$, there exist sequences $(x_n)$ in $F$ and $(y_n)$ in $K$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\to0$. Since $K$ is compact, a subsequence $(y_{n_k})$ of $(y_n)$ is convergent. Since
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}d(x_{n_k},y)=0
$$
(prove it) we can conclude that $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $y$. Since $F$ is closed, $y\in F\cap K$.

Comment: but is the first one closed?

Comment: @TanEma The first is the whole space; find $F$ and $K$ yourself.

Comment: @TanEma:  Note that in egreg's second example the sets are closed, so indeed we cannot prove a nonempty intersection in general.  However if one of the sets $F,K$ is *compact*, then you can prove it for a complete metric space.

Comment: @hardmath why do you need completeness?

Comment: @JensRenders:  It is redundant; I mentioned it for contrast with the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. For instance, take:
\begin{align*}
F := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq \exp(x) \}\\
K := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \leq -\exp(x)\}\\
\end{align*}

which are both closed as inverse image of closed sets by continuous applications. As $x \rightarrow -\infty$, the two sets get closer and closer to each other, but they never intersect.

To make this counterexample, we had somehow to use the fact that both $F$ and $K$ were not bounded. We can show that if either $K$ or $F$ is compact, then necessarily $F \cap K \neq \emptyset$.